# Insert form data into MySQL database using Rest Web Services using Java, AJAX

Tags: java, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to insert a record into MySQL database using HTML form. I am using AJAX to call web services in Java. But it is not working. It gives an alert saying false. When I tried with POSTMAN it works fine. But using AJAX it's not working.
Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Code in Add.jsp

```
    <body>
        <form id="submit">
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="text" name="password"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#submit").submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "http://localhost:8080/WebService/webresources/users/insert",
            data: formToJSON(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) 
            {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                alert('Error: ' + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
});

    function formToJSON() 
    {
        return JSON.stringify
        ({
            "username": $('#username').val(),
            "email": $('#email').val(),
            "password": $('#password').val()
        });
    };
    </script>
```

Code in Service

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/insert")
public boolean insertUsers(String content)
{
     Gson g = new Gson();
     Users u = (Users) g.fromJson(content, Users.class);

     UsersDAO dao = new UsersDAO();
     return dao.insertUsers(u);
}
```

Comment: What's inside `Users` class? Did you use debugger?

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko Getters and Setters are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `id` for all the input fields.

Try this.

```
<body>
        <form id="submit">
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br><br>

            <button id="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </body>
```

And in this, You have to change this,

```
$("#submit").submit(function(event)
```

into this,

```
$("#submit").click(function(event)
```